# Как сделать элемент который показан рисунку в MS WORD

Tags: ms-word

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать данную линию в Word и указать примерное расположение этого инструмента?

Comment: Символ табуляции, подчёркнутый шрифт.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую при возможности не впечатывать миллионы табуляций, а вставить в документ нормальное оглавление: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-882e8564-0edb-435e-84b5-1d8552ccf0c0

Как изменить стили (например, вместо стандартной пунктирной линии сделать сплошную) - можно посмотреть здесь:
https://neumeka.ru/oglavlenie.html